# Minikube: bash: /usr/local/bin/minikube: No such file or directory

Tags: kubernetes

I just installed Minikube for my Kubernetes local setup on Ubuntu 18.04 using the following command:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube_latest_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i minikube_latest_amd64.deb
```

However, when I run the command:

```
minikube start
```

I get the following error:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/minikube: No such file or directory
```

I'm really wondering what the issue will be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just figured it out after some research and trial.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I simply closed that terminal and opened a new one, and ran the command again:

```
minikube start
```

OR

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

And it worked fine.

**Note**: By default `minikube` attempts to use `Docker` as the driver, but you specify `VirtualBox` as your preferred driver, which has some advantages.

Another way would have been to reload the Ubuntu bash terminal:

```
bash --login
```

**Note**:

If all the above techniques do not work, you add the Minikube executable to your path:

```
sudo mv minikube /usr/local/bin
```

You can then verify the Minikube executable path:

```
which minikube.
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**